# Unable to overlay elements over full progress bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem overlaying an element inside a bootstrap progress bar.

The icons are overplayed on the partly filled progress bar, but on the full progress bar the icons aren't displayed.

Comment: Can you show us the basic html you are using ? As i can see, you icon get below the container and hides when the full bar shows

Comment: Please update the link, it's currently giving a 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result by applying the following code to the progress element and the div containing your icons.

Apply `position: relative;` to the `.progress` element styles:

```
<div class="progress" style="position: relative;">
```

Apply `position: absolute; top: 0; right: 7px;` to the `div` element wrapping the icons:

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 7px">
    <!-- icon elements -->
</div>
```

Full example solution (taken from your code and modified):

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active" style="background: #ddd; position: relative;">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width: 100%; float: left;"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 7px;">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> 
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

The icons is display even in full progress bar, but the icons is overwritten by progress bar. You can fixed it by create your own CSS and add `z-index: 0;` in your icons style

```
.modal-footer span{
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They are using float left... So the bar pushes them.

Try using absolute position on the div that holds the icons.